# Is there something like sync-gateway to MongoDb?

Tags: php, android, node.js, mongodb, couchbase

Hello everyone I'm trying to do a proyect, this proyect had an android aplication, a simply Rest web service in PHP or Nodejs and a Couchbase like database with its own server. But I'm having a lot of problems with couchbase, I can't connect with PHP neither NodeJs, so I tried to connect NodeJs with MongoDB and It Works!, but I wanted to use Couchbase because I liked sync-gateway for android aplications, so my question is if is there a sync-gateway for mongodb?.

Sorry for my english.
Thank you so much.

Comment: what problems do you have with connecting to Couchbase from php or node.js?